# How to compare a file with a commit from X versions ago

Tags: git, diff

To compare a file with a certain commit that is not the current HEAD, I call `git log`, note the commit hash and then call `git diff <hash> filename`.

Is there a way to use the diff command like this: `git diff -<x_commits_back> filename` and compare the file with a version from `x` versions ago?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
git diff HEAD~X -- filename
```

Replace `X` as appropriate. Note that it follows the first parent of merge commits.

Comment: Works as advertised. Thank you